# AWS DynamoDb: Querying for multiple items matching comparison operator

Tags: amazon-web-services

Say I'm implementing Uber and I have a table like this:

```
Table: Cars
Row: carId=A, city=SF, driverId=52
Row: carId=B, city=LA, driverId=285
Row: carId=C, city=SF, driverId=547
Row: carId=D, city=SF, driverId=125
Row: carId=E, city=LA, driverId=876
Row: carId=F, city=NY, driverId=92
```

And I have a global secondary index on 'city'.

Now I would like to run a query, "What are all the cars in city=SF or city=LA".  Is there a way to do this using the global secondary index?

Clearly I could use a Scan and have Dynamo look at every row, but I'm hoping Query can do it more efficiently.

BTW here's my current attempt:

```
List<AttributeValue> attributeValueList = new ArrayList<>();
String[] cities = {"LA", "SF"};
for (String city : cities) {
    attributeValueList.add(new AttributeValue().withS(city));
}

QueryRequest queryRequest = new QueryRequest()
        .withTableName("Cars")
        .withIndexName("Cars-city-index")
        .withSelect("ALL_ATTRIBUTES");
HashMap<String, Condition> keyConditions = new HashMap<String, Condition>();
keyConditions.put("city", new Condition()
        .withComparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.IN)
        .withAttributeValueList(attributeValueList));
queryRequest.setKeyConditions(keyConditions);
```

But this fails with error "Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation":

```
Caused by: com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Attempted conditional constraint is not an indexable operation (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 9LH0D9K02CAS078M3C06R8T4D7VV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:820)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:439)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:245)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:2908)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.query(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1064)
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge you can only run one equality condition for hash keys regardless of whether they are a global secondary index. Here is what the [AWS doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryAndScan.html) says:

> "Query supports a specific set of comparison operators for choosing key values. You must specify the hash key attribute name and value as an equality condition. You can optionally specify a second condition, referring to the range key attribute; this condition allows you to choose from several conditional operators"
>
> "If your table has one or more secondary indexes, you can Query those indexes in the same way that you query a table"

So I guess the best option for you here is to run two queries and join the results. Or if you have a lot of values then you would have to run a scan with a filter containing an `IN` comparison operator. This kind of problem is very ill suited to NoSQL, you would definitely be better off using a relational database in this scenario.

Hope this helps